# Cycles reflective materials not rendering transparency correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, reflection

A reflective material in Cycles will reflect the world color even if the world color has an alpha of 0. If the world has a transparent material, the reflective material will show black pixels instead of transparency.

Example:

[image: The plane on the left has a simple glossy shader with roughness 0. It reflects the cube and the world color, even though the world color has alpha 0. As you can see (behind the cube itself), the render properties are also set to allow transparent background. The glossy shader doesn't support alpha it seems, which is a bug in my opinion.]

The plane on the left is a has a simple glossy shader with roughness 0. It reflects the cube and the world color, even though the world color has alpha 0. As you can see (behind the cube itself), the render properties are also set to allow transparent background. The glossy shader doesn't support alpha it seems, which is a bug in my opinion.

Example 2:

[image: Here the world is set to transparent but the glossy shader is still not rendering transparency.]

Here the world is set to transparent but the glossy shader is still not rendering transparency.
The principled shader has this issue as well.

Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Sorry, this is intended to happen. However, you might be able to have a workaround by setting the world color to bright green, and then green screening the reflections out. First though, have you tried the “film -> transparent background” setting in the render tab?

Comment: The Film -> Transparent checkbox is on. I could use green screening, but some of the other reflections in my scene will also be green so it would be a pain to deal with.